# how to send html templates in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

```
Emailservicerequest.Email = new Email();
            Emailservicerequest.Email.FromEmail = Insertcampaignrequest.Campaign.SenderAddress;
            Emailservicerequest.Email.ToEmail = Insertcampaignrequest.Campaign.RecipientsFilter;
            Emailservicerequest.Email.Subject = Insertcampaignrequest.Campaign.Subject;

           // Emailservicerequest.Email = true;

            Emailservicerequest.Email.Body = Convert.ToString(MailFormat.Html);
            Emailservicerequest.Email.Body = "Provider/EmailTemplate/email.html";
 Emailserviceresponse=Emailservice.SendEmail(Emailservicerequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net 4.0 you should use T4 Templates to create email templates. its easy and yet manageable.

for more info 
http://asmiki.com/2011/05/20/using-t4-templates-for-compiling-net-email-templates/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To convert your HTML file into a string so that you can set it as Body value to your email Object you can use the below function:

```
public string ReturnHTML(string Path)
     {
         string strBody = "";
         try
            {
                StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(Path);
                strBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                objReader.Close();
            }
         catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strBody = "";
                throw ex;
            }
            return strBody;
     }
```

call the above function in your code

```
string path = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoticeApprovalPath"].ToString());
string tempStr = cmm.ReturnHTML(path);
tempStr = tempStr.Replace("[xxxNoticeIDxxx]", Convert.ToString(RequestID));
```

replace function is used to replace the values in HTML Template:

Here `[xxxNoticeIDxxx]` is replace with the value `RequestID` variable containing the data.